# How to detect if an event is sent by an argument

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I don't know if it is called an argument (i.e. `textbox1.text = "Hello";`).

I have a control and there is a text box in it. It has a dropdown box that opens when the text is changed. But when I update the text in the text box that box drops down.

I need a way to make it so it only drops down if someone manually does it.

```
TBAddressBar.ABText.Text = getCurrentBrowser().Source.ToString();
```

and

```
    public void ABText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == 1*)
        {
            ABDropDown.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            ABDropDown.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you open the dropdown when text is changed in textbos? Do you do it manually with event or do you have binding with a trigger? Can you post xaml if there's trigger involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone manually does it, presumably they are using keypresses to do so. In that case, use [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx) or [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keyup.aspx) events to show the dropdown instead.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past is use a boolean variable that I set when I update my textboxes programically to bypass the TextChangedEvent.

i.e.

```
bool loading;

....

loading =true;

TBAddressBar.ABText.Text = getCurrentBrowser().Source.ToString(); 

loading = false;

public void ABText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(loading) return;
    ....
}
```

Comment: thats a bad way to go considering everywhere he is changing the text programmatically, he need to write two extra lines of code. The ideal way is handle key down event.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just remove the code from your TextChanged Event.

Anyway you got the basic idea.. Now do your dropdown logic in KeyPress event, since it accepts only characters and not the modifiers. So it behaves closer to your requirement. Not that you cant handle the same using KeyDown and KeyUp, you can, but more code..

Comment: No, I want to keep it but detect what the sender is.

Comment: @Thaky you got the answer anyway. I could not understand fully from your description. The right way is to handle your code in the right event, that is a keypress event in my opinion..